# Is there any command line available to minimize the teamviewer's toolbar?

Tags: command-line, teamviewer

I am looking for the command line to minimize the teamviewer's toolbar, i.e. at dos command `teamviewer.exe --id <remote machine> --Password <rm teamviwer password>`.

Comment: Maybe a macro recorder would help? If you can code simple programs then it would be easy to do with [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/)